# libstdc++.so.6 is linking to the wrong version

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc

In the past, my ignorance has led me to messing around with gcc/g++ version. As of current, I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04** and running `gcc --version` gave me this:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

However, after some debugging, I realised that my libstdc++.so.6 is linking against the wrong version. I knew about this by running `ls -l  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`, which gave me:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 May 19  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28
```

Checking against the [ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), apparently it came from gcc 9.3.0, which I do remember installing at one point. This has caused me some weird bugs when programming C++.

Now, I would like to link libstdc++.so.6 back to gcc 8 but I'm not sure what's the less idiotic way to do this. Should I try removing GCC 9 and reinstall GCC 8?

Running `locate libstdc++.so.6` gave me this:

```
/opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2020.3.2/host-linux-x64/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2020.3.2/target-linux-armv8/host-linux-armv8/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core18/1988/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core18/1988/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/snap/core18/1988/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
/snap/core18/2066/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core18/2066/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/snap/core18/2066/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py
```

Comment: AFAIK, `libstdc++6.0.xx` is not related to a particular gcc version - it's part of a standalone `libstdc++6` package. What actual problem(s) are you trying to solve?

Comment: @steeldriver It seems like my binaries is linking to the wrong shared libary (libstdc++.so.6) which caused the program to crash (seg fault)

Comment: What if you tried removing the package that `libstdc++6.0.28` belongs to and then installing the one that you want?  That is, ignore gcc 8 or 9 issue.

Comment: What should I do to figure out which packages depends on libstdc++6.0.28?

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -S libstdc++.so.6` and `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S libstdc++.so.6 | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u)` to the question.

Comment: I really think you should do some more debugging on the cause(s) of the segfaults before going down this rabbit hole - AFAIK libstdc++ always provides *backward* ABI compatibility ex. on my 18.04 box (where I have libstdc++6.0.29.so) it provides CXX ABIs from 1.3.1 (gcc 4.?) to 1.3.13 (gcc 11.1), as indicated by the output of `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29 | grep CXXABI`